# Transition of removeclass() in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to set `transition` in `removeclass`method.

When I add classes,`transition-duration` works well,but when I remove class by clicking `undo` button,`transition` doesn't work.

How can I set `transition-duration` in`removeClass`?

Best regards

```js
$(function() {
  let clicked = [];
  $("td").click(function() {
    let clickedID = $(this).attr('id');
    clicked.push(clickedID);
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
  });
  $("#undo").on('click',() => {
    if(clicked.length) {
      let lastClicked = clicked.pop();
      $(`td#${lastClicked}`).removeClass("aqua");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}


td {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>

<button id="undo">undo</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove the class `aqua` the `transition` property also is lost

```js
$(function() {
  let clicked = [];
  $("td").click(function() {
    let clickedID = $(this).attr('id');
    clicked.push(clickedID);
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
  });
  $("#undo").on('click',() => {
    if(clicked.length) {
      let lastClicked = clicked.pop();
      $(`td#${lastClicked}`).removeClass("aqua");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.transition td{
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="transition">
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>

<button id="undo">undo</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add transition in TD.

```js
$(function() {
  let clicked = [];
  $("td").click(function() {
    let clickedID = $(this).attr('id');
    clicked.push(clickedID);
    $(this).addClass("aqua");
  });
  $("#undo").on('click',() => {
    if(clicked.length) {
      let lastClicked = clicked.pop();
      $(`td#${lastClicked}`).removeClass("aqua");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.aqua{
  background-color: aqua;
}


td {
  padding: 5px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td id="1">1</td>
  <td id="2">2</td>
  <td id="3">3</td>
  <td id="4">4</td>
  <td id="5">5</td>
  <td id="6">6</td>
  <td id="7">7</td>
  <td id="8">8</td>
  <td id="9">9</td>
  <td id="10">10</td>
</table>

<button id="undo">undo</button>
```